# Create a backspace button for html/javascript-based textarea

Tags: javascript, html, button, backspace

I have a created a virtual keyboard to decipher a puzzle code on a html/java page, however I am unable to work out how to add a backspace or linebreak button to avoid having to mouseclick the textarea to backspace every time a single mistake is made or need a new line.

Code for the page is added below, any ideas to do this as simply as possible would be greatly appreciated, as I'm still learning Javascript and havent quite got my head around some events yet.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <HTML>
 <head>
<!--JQuery activation-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-8">

<div id="letters">
<!-- PLCKFBG HMOERJ AQNXYIZ VWSUT,.123456789O (and space) cypher alphabet-->
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="P" style="width:100%"  id="A" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="L" style="width:100%"  id="B" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="C" style="width:100%"  id="C" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="K" style="width:100%"  id="D" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="F" style="width:100%"  id="E" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="B" style="width:100%"  id="F" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="G" style="width:100%"  id="G" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="D" style="width:100%"  id="H" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="H" style="width:100%"  id="I" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="M" style="width:100%"  id="J" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="O" style="width:100%"  id="K" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="E" style="width:100%"  id="L" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="R" style="width:100%"  id="M" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="J" style="width:100%"  id="N" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="A" style="width:100%"  id="O" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="Q" style="width:100%"  id="P" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="N" style="width:100%"  id="Q" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="X" style="width:100%"  id="R" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="Y" style="width:100%"  id="S" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="I" style="width:100%"  id="T" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="Z" style="width:100%"  id="U" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="V" style="width:100%"  id="V" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="W" style="width:100%"  id="W" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="S" style="width:100%"  id="X" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="U" style="width:100%"  id="Y" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="T" style="width:100%"  id="Z" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="." style="width:100%"  id="." />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="," style="width:100%"  id="," />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="1" style="width:100%"  id="1" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="2" style="width:100%"  id="2" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="3" style="width:100%"  id="3" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="4" style="width:100%"  id="4" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="5" style="width:100%"  id="5" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="6" style="width:100%"  id="6" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="7" style="width:100%"  id="7" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="8" style="width:100%"  id="8" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="9" style="width:100%"  id="9" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Wingdings'" value="A" style="width:100%"  id="O" />
<input type="submit" style="font-family:'Copperplate'" value="[Space]" style="width:100%"  id=" " />
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

<!-- Clear button -->
<div id="clearbutton">   
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="javascript:eraseText();"> 
</div>

<!-- textarea "translation"-->
<textarea id="translation" class="form control ChangeMe" name="translation" rows=10 cols=50 placeholder="Common Translation"></textarea>
</div>
</div>


<script>
// code for letter translation
$(document).ready(function(){
  var txt=$('#translation');
  $("#letters").on('click','input',function() {
    txt.val(txt.val()+this.id);
  });
 });


//Clear Button Function 
function eraseText() {
document.getElementById("translation").value = "";
}

//disable backspace outside of text boxes
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
                var element = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                if ((element != 'input' && element != 'textarea') || $(e.target).attr("readonly") || (e.target.getAttribute("type") ==="checkbox")) {
                    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Off topic:_ I would recommend to use this in your CSS: `input {font-family: 'wingdings';}` it cleans up a lot.

Comment: _off topic:_ there are two buttons with value of "A"

Comment: Originally tried that, but the full page uses multiple fonts and it ended up a mess. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backspace key should just chop off the last character of the textarea right? So, just make the backspace key set the textarea's value to the textarea's value minus the last character using [JavaScript's substring method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp). Here's some [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode):

```
function onPressBackspace() {
    myTextarea.value = myTextarea.value.substring(0, myTextarea.value.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserting a new line is just as simple as 1+1. Just put `\\\n` into the code.

```
$("newLineButton").on("click",function(){
$("#translation").text()=$("#translation").text()+"\\\n";
});
```

Comment: _Off topic: You have two buttons with the value of 'A'._

Answer (score -1):

```
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function backSpace() {
                var bsp = document.getElementById("ns").value;
                document.getElementById("ns").value=bsp.substring(0,bsp.length -1);
            }
       </script>
   </head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="ns">
```

Comment: check my second answer. I made a few mistakes in this

Comment: Just a note for next time, you can [edit] your answers by clicking the "edit" link just below the text in your answer. Seems you've already posted a new answer, you should delete this one by clicking the "delete" link.

Answer (score -1):

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function backSpace() {
                    var bsp = document.getElementById("ns").value;
                    document.getElementById("ns").value=bsp.substring(0,bsp.length-1);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="ns" onClick="backSpace()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure your input type is always text

Answer (score -2):

```js
const backSpace=document.getElementById('backSpace')
const textBox=document.getElementById('textBox')

backSpace.addEventListener('click',function(){
textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, textBox.value.length-1)
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="backSpace">BackSpace</button>
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox">
</body>
</html>
```